# C# Winforms The type or namespace name 'Properties' could not be found in the global namespace

Tags: c#, winforms, properties, namespaces

Whenever I try to build or open a form designer file I keep getting the error `CS0400: The type or namespace name 'Properties' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)`
The Resources file has the correct namespace.
The properties folder does exist.
Visual studio does not find any errors while trying to use the properties file except when the project runs where it throws an exception because it cant find an image in the properties file which exists.

Properties file: https://github.com/Soniczac7/Download-Manager/blob/master/Properties/Resources.resx

Example designer file: https://github.com/Soniczac7/Download-Manager/blob/master/WebViewWindow.Designer.cs

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the global namespace issue by changing the code from `global::Properties.Resources` to `global::DownloadManager.Properties.Resources`
and to fix the excpetion on triyign to load the resources I had to change the string "Properties.Resources" to "DownloadManager.Properties.Resources".

Before:

```cs
internal static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager ResourceManager {
            get {
                if (object.ReferenceEquals(resourceMan, null)) {
                    global::System.Resources.ResourceManager temp = new global::System.Resources.ResourceManager("Properties.Resources", typeof(Resources).Assembly);
                    resourceMan = temp;
                }
                return resourceMan;
            }
        }
```

After:

```cs
internal static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager ResourceManager {
            get {
                if (object.ReferenceEquals(resourceMan, null)) {
                    global::System.Resources.ResourceManager temp = new global::System.Resources.ResourceManager("DownloadManager.Properties.Resources", typeof(Resources).Assembly);
                    resourceMan = temp;
                }
                return resourceMan;
            }
        }
```

After that any resource exceptions stopped.